# How to query nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have documents like

```
{
    name: "name1",
    friends: [
        {
            name: "name2",
            thingsWeDo: [
                {
                    name: "running",
                    like_it: true
                },
                {
                    name: "swimming",
                    like_it: false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So if I want to know the name of my friend we both love swimming, how do I do it?

I know the schema design could be better, but if I want to query this schema, how do I do it?

is it possible to chain `$elemMatch` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `friends` and `thingsWeDo` in [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and then use `$match` to match your criteria. Check below query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$friends" // first unwind friends array 
}, {
  "$unwind": "$friends.thingsWeDo" // second unwind friends.thingsWeDo
}, {
  "$match": {
    "friends.thingsWeDo.name": "swimming", // match your criteria
    "friends.thingsWeDo.like_it": false
  }
}, {
  "$project": {
    "name": "$friends.thingsWeDo.name",
    "like_it": "$friends.thingsWeDo.like_it"
  }
}).pretty()
```

here `unwind` two times for large documents query will be slow down. As per my recommendation you should change your schema structure and try to avoid `unwinding`

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but something like this should do:

```
Model.find({ 
  $and: [ 
    { "friends.thingsWeDo.name": 'swimming' }, 
    { "friends.thingsWeDo.like_it": true } 
  ] 
}, function (err, docs) {

});
```